# What is the correct phrase to ask to determine which group a first nations person considers themselves to be part of?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, political-correctness, cultural-phrases

I met a women who I gathered was First Nations. I struggled to ask the question to elicit the response to find more about her heritage and culture. What is the word that distinguishes between different North American aboriginal people? I've heard them called "nations" but it would be ambiguous to ask "what Nation are you from?" because the "official" one would be Canada.

For example would it be politically correct to ask "What type of First Nations are you?" or "Are you part of a certain band?". I was looking for an answer like "Cree" or "Salish".

Comment: You might ask if this person still preserves their tribal identity?

Comment: In Canada, a person of First Nations' descent is usually part of a *band*.  I cannot speak for American usage, but here it is perfectly acceptable to ask 'what band are you from?'

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but that's a yes or no question, would it be correct to ask "what tribe are you part of"? It sounds strange...

Comment: @Celeritas If they answer yes to having a tribal identity, then "What tribe (or band) do you belong?" seems polite to me.

Answer (score 2):

You might be surprised to find out that many **[Native Americans](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1369572/Native-American-Self-Names)** don't like that politically correct name for our indiginous Americans.

> **Native Americans** did not suffer through countless trails of tears, disease, wars, and cultural annihilation -- **Indians did**. The Native people today are Native Americans not Indians, therefore we do not need to feel guilty for the horrors of the past. Many Indians feel that this is what the term Native American essentially does -- it white-washes history. It cleans the slate.

So what to call [them](http://www.allthingscherokee.com/articles_culture_events_070101.html)? **All Things Chreokee** explores this, and their recommendation:

> When you don't know the specific tribe simply use the term which you are most comfortable using. The worst that can happen is that someone might correct you and open the door for a thoughtful debate on the subject of political correctness and its impact on ethnic identity. What matters in the long run is not which term is used but the intention with which it is used. ...the term "Indian" is increasingly falling back into use.

Comment: *"The worst that can happen is that someone might correct you"* - I think there are worse possible results than that.

Comment: @nnnnnn - This might be the pickiest and least helpful comment I've ever gotten. They aren't even my words to address. Congrats.

Comment: I was serious. A person following the (quoted - I know it wasn't your words) advice may cause offence.

Comment: I'm sure you were. That's what's so surprising that I responded to your comment. My response remains unchanged. (Are you new to the site? Do you know the reason for comments? Reading the help section will, well, *help* you to understand the site.)

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate term is "tribal affiliation"

> Tribal affiliation means an association with federally recognized Indian tribes or bands.

[Law insider: Tribal affiliation](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/tribal-affiliation#:%7E:text=Tribal%20affiliation%20means%20an%20association%20with%20federally%20recognized%20Indian%20tribes%20or%20bands.)

... which isn't to suggest that it is always appropriate to ask.

Answer (score -2):

The primary division of Indian/Native American groups in the US is the **Tribe**.

Although increasingly, you could make a case for "Casino".

Comment: What's the source of "Casino"? That may be considered an offensive joke where I'm from because, confidently, casinos are often near First Nations reserves.